# DRY Rails array displayed as 2 Bootstrap rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have a pretty basic Rails array and I'm displaying it as a 2x2 grid of butons. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have two different `row` divs with two different `col-md-6` divs on each. I'm writing more or less the exact same line of code 4 times and iIf it weren't for the two 'row' divs, I could just DRY this up. How do I handle this?

```
<div id="answers">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><%= button_to @choices[0].answer, "#", class: "btn btn-default btn-answer", method: :post %></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><%= button_to @choices[1].answer, "#", class: "btn btn-default btn-answer", method: :post %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><%= button_to @choices[2].answer, "#", class: "btn btn-default btn-answer", method: :post %></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><%= button_to @choices[3].answer, "#", class: "btn btn-default btn-answer", method: :post %></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will there always be 4 choices or could it vary?

Comment: Hi @Beartech, it will only be 4. I'm just keeping it at 2x2 for the moment to keep the layout clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      <% choices.each_slice(2) do |first_two| %>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6"><%= button_to first_two[0].answer , "#", class: "btn btn-default btn-answer", method: :post %></div>
             <div class="col-md-6"><%= button_to first_two[1].answer, "#", class: "btn btn-default btn-answer", method: :post %></div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

DRYs it up some. You could even make each half of the code around `<%= first_two[1] %>` a variable and do each line like `<%= puts variable_1 + first_two[0] + variable_2 %>`

or even more DRY:

```
<% choices.each_slice(2) do |first_two| %>
          <div class="row">
             <% first_two.each do |choice| %>
               <div class="col-md-6"><%= button_to choice.answer, "#", class: "btn btn-default btn-answer", method: :post %></div>
             <% end %>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

If you are going to do this over and over on a page I would define a helper method that does all of this, that way you just call the helper method with the array and it spits them all out.

Comment: I'm no Rails expert, so I don't know if it would be rails-ish to put everything you have in your question into a helper method that produces the HTML so you would just call it with the @choices array and it would build the entire thing. Is that mixing too much view code into a method?

Comment: You have 7 lines instead of 8, but if you want to make a change to the button, you only have to do it once. So that is the savings I see in it.

Comment: Hi @Beartech, thanks for the input. I get an error when I try to use `slice(2)` on that array:    `NoMethodError in Exams#show
Showing /home/tom/rails/oplei/app/views/exams/_quiz.html.erb where line #8 raised:undefined method 'slice' for #<Enumerator:0x007f91e06d94c0>
Extracted source (around line #8):      
   
   
   
    <% @choices.each.slice(2) do |first_two| %>
     

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/exams/show.html.erb`

Comment: Sorry! I had each.slice instead of each_slice. Just ran the above code using Rails console in an app and it worked.